Recursive Type in Zod for Record
How to declare recursive Zod schema for record?
Like say I have:
Schema = {
title: string,
properties: {
   XYZ: {
        title: string
        code: string,
        properties: {
              ABC: {
                 title: string,
                 code: string
              }
        },
   },
}

Here, properties is a record(string).
I want it to be recursive, but I saw online and it was done with arrays only. Is there a solution for it?
I went through this link, but this has been done for arrays and I tried similar for record, it's not coming.

Here is how you define your recursive schema:

Define the base schema for the non-recursive title and code fields.

Extend the base schema and recursively define the properties field.


import { z } from "zod";

const propertiesSchema = z.object({ 
  title: z.string(), 
  code: z.string().optional()
})

type Properties = z.infer<typeof propertiesSchema> & {
  properties?: Record<string, Properties>;
};

const schema: z.ZodType<Properties>  = propertiesSchema.extend({
  properties: z.lazy(() => z.record(schema)).optional() 
}).strict();


Code Sandbox

But now say I want to have
